# How to automate webpage under a closed shadowDOM

Tags: ui-automation, shadow-dom

A part of the webpage is under closed shadow root mode. How do we automate it through selenium or javascript?

**Edit:**
we can see the DOM under the shadow in chrome://inspect/#apps. This seems to be the child DOM.
Is it possible to communicate between parent DOM and the above child DOM to perform actions on child DOM when our ShadowRoot DOM is hindering us to automate?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: You can't.

More complex answer:

Override the `Element.prototype.attachShadow` function to override the `closed` setting and force it to be `open`.

Or rewrite your components to not use `closed`. This could be done with the components checking a query parameter and using closed most of the time and open when in testing mode.

**UPDATE**

A closed component is an attempt to allow the component creator some level of security that no one else can mess up their component. While the developer tools can still see inside, the outside code can't unless the component exposes the `shadowRoot` in some way.

What a closed component should do, instead of exposing their `shadowRoot` is to provide enough properties and functions to allow the user of the component to do everything they need.

Think of the [`<video>` element](https://devdocs.io/dom/htmlvideoelement). They have dozens of properties between it and its parent element `HTMLMediaElement` and dozens of functions and events. The component has everything needed for the users of `<video>` to be able to do almost anything.

If we write our component in this way then being close should not be an issue.

Sometimes people want to test every aspect of a Web Component, but they should really only focus on the public interface and not worry about the inner DOM.

How do you test an `<input>` element. Most of the time you set `.value = "some value";` or add an event listener on `change` or `input`.

As long as your components properly expose everything needed to be able to test them then being close should no longer be an issue.

Comment: we can see the DOM under the shadow in chrome://inspect/#apps. Is it possible to communicate between parent DOM and the above child DOM to perform actions on child DOM?

Comment: This is normally done by having the parent code call functions or set properties and attributes on the component. It is then the job of the component to adjust its internal DOM. This allows for separation of concerns and keeps your component reusable. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

Comment: Okay! That was quite an interesting fact. But how do we mimic the communication between the parent and child components?

Comment: The idea is to have some test pages that allow your global JS code to interact with each component. Then you can validate everything through the public interface (properties, attributes and functions). If you have a WC with child WCs and they are in a closed DOM then you won't be able to test the inner DOM elements unless you provide a way to get them `'open'`. If they are not open then treat them like a black box and only test the public interface. This is no different than testing a 3rd party library. But if you really need to test all interactions on a full page, then you must make it open.